# vbscript error trying to connect to access database

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, compiler-errors, vba

This is the script:

```
Option Explicit
'Supported in Access 2003 and newer versions
'Add a reference to "Microsoft Access xx.0 Object Library"
'or change code to do Late Binding to support multiple Access versions
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim oApp As Access.Application
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\student_id_Ft Lupton.mdb", Exclusive:=False
    oApp.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
               DataSource:="Ft_lupton", _
               DataTarget:="C:\fortlupton.xml"
    oApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    oApp.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

`script: forltuptontest.vbs
line: 6
Char: 14
Error: expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error`

not sure what is wrong with line 6 character 14

after the wonderful help from the answer by:HansUp

here is a working version of the script which is exactly what I needed.

updated code looks like this:

```
Dim oApp
Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Const acExportTable = 0
Const acQuitSaveNone = 2
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\users\amoore19\desktop\Database\student_id_Ft Lupton.mdb", False
oApp.ExportXML 0, "Ft_lupton", "C:\users\amoore19\desktop\fortlupton.xml"
oApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
oApp.Quit 2
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Since you defined the constants, you could do `oApp.ExportXML acExportTable` if that seems clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the working solution from HansUp, which worked great is:

```
Dim oApp
Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
Const acExportTable = 0
Const acQuitSaveNone = 2
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\users\amoore19\desktop\Database\student_id_Ft Lupton.mdb", False
oApp.ExportXML 0, "Ft_lupton", "C:\users\amoore19\desktop\fortlupton.xml"
oApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
oApp.Quit 2
Set oApp = Nothing`
```

Answer (score 2):

`Dim [variable name] As [something]` is not supported in VBScript.  All variables are variants, and `Dim ... As` triggers an error.

You can eliminate the error with this change ...

```vb
'Dim oApp As Access.Application
Dim oApp
```

Unfortunately, the script host complains about the first error it encounters and stops there.  After you fix that first error, you will see more.

VBScript doesn't know about Access named constants, so you must supply the value of each constant instead of its name.

- 0 for *acExportTable*
- 2 for *acQuitSaveNone*

Or you could define the constants in your script if you prefer and then continue to use their names.

```vb
Const acExportTable = 0
Const acQuitSaveNone = 2
```

VBScript can't deal with named options for Access methods.  So you must discard the option names and pass the option values in their expected order.

```vb
'oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\student_id_Ft Lupton.mdb", Exclusive:=False
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\student_id_Ft Lupton.mdb", False
'oApp.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
'           DataSource:="Ft_lupton", _
'           DataTarget:="C:\fortlupton.xml"
oApp.ExportXML 0, "Ft_lupton", "C:\fortlupton.xml"
```

Finally, after you fix the errors, your script won't do anything because the executable statements are inside a subroutine: `Command1_Click()`

You could run the subroutine by adding `Call Command1_Click()` on the line after `End Sub`.  However, I don't see why a subroutine is needed here; you can just discard `Private Sub Command1_Click()` and `End Sub`.

Comment: you are amazing. my updated coded has been added above

Comment: Hey Hans, one more question for you. if I have multiple .mdb files that i want to export to multiple or even one xml file. I know i can do this same export multiple times. but is there anyway to do like a *.mdb for the database and then export with a number stagger or export all to one xml. like adding one to the next?

Comment: It would be easy to pull from each of several db files, but I don't see how to add their data to an existing XML file.  Perhaps you could try a query which `UNION`s the data from those tables and then export the query to XML.